# Is there an elementary continuous function which is positive only if all arguments are?

Tags: functions

I am looking for a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n) > 0$ if and only if $x_i > 0 \ \forall i = 1,2, \ldots , n$. Can anyone suggest a good one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(x)=\displaystyle \min_i x_i$ is simple and continuous.

It is essentially the same as pseudoDust's answer, with $\lt$ changed to $\le$.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a nice one, but:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_0  \; \; \; \; \; \;  x_0<x_1,x_2,...,x_n\\ 
x_1  \; \; \; \; \; \;  x_1<x_0,x_2,...,x_n\\ 
...\\ 
x_n  \; \; \; \; \; \;  x_n<x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1}
\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: This is ill defined. What is $f(a,\ldots ,a)$?

Comment: @GitGud I'll let you guess...

Comment: It was a rethorical question.